# How to prove this by mean value theorem? $f(y)=f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)+\frac{1}{2}(y-x)^T\nabla^2f(x+a(y-x))(y-x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

How to prove this by mean value theorem?

$f(y)=f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)+\frac{1}{2}(y-x)^T\nabla^2f(x+a(y-x))(y-x)$
where $a\in[0,1]$.

The mean-value theorem is

$\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=\nabla f(x+a(y-x))$
also, $a\in[0,1]$.

Comment: If you have understood the multi-variable analogue of Mean value theorem, this can be proved with a slight manipulation. Assuming f is a real-valued function, define a 1-variable function $g(a) = f( x + a(y-x))$ .Its then about invoking the Taylor Series for this 1-var function. Check out Apostol's Analysis book, chapter 12 I reckon. Hope this helps.

Comment: I said f is real valued as you have used the gradient symbol rather than the Total Derivative $Df$

Comment: @Vishesh, Hi, I check the book. But I cannot find the proof.

Comment: Okay first off, $\nabla g$ does not make sense, as g is just a function of 1 variable i.e.$a$ or do you mean to say $g'(a)$? I meant expand the function $g$ as a function of $a$ using the Taylor's series you know. Do you wish me to give you the answer explicitly??I can do that if you wish, but I just thought that you might have got it after so long..

Comment: And as for the book reference, I guess my memory has failed me or maybe you need to tweak what is there a bit to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the answer here:

You have already seen that $g(1) = f(y) $, $g(0) = f(x)$, where $g(t) = f(x+t(y-x))$ ,

By Taylor's series for 1 variable functions:

$$ g(1) = g(0) + g'(0) + \frac{1}{2} g^"(a) ,\; 0<a<1 \ldots\ldots\ldots(1)$$

Note that $g'(t) = \nabla f(x +t(y-x)) . (y-x)$ by the chain rule for derivatives.This gives $g'(0) = \nabla f(x) .(y-x)$

Again by chain rule, $g^"(t) = \sum D_i(\sum D_j f(x +t(y-x))(y-x)_j)(y-x)_i = (y-x)^T \nabla^2f(x+t(y-x))(y-x)\ldots(2) $

This is a quadratic form in case you know them from before. No plug in $t=a$ in $(2)$ and then substitute what you have got for $g^"(a)$ and $g'(0)$ back in $(1)$. You will get what you desire.

Comment: Also apologise for stupidly using $a$ as the parameter in place of $t$ in the comments, my bad.